# Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, slim

I'm using Eloquent in combination with Slim Framework to build a small API. For some reason, I am getting this error, and I can't locate the problem:

```
Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable.
```

Database settings are correct. This error is thrown in my staging environment on the server. Locally, with MySQL 5.6.29, it works perfectly. Although I don't think it's related to MySQL 5.7 because I have another app running on the same server with the same version of Eloquent.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm using:

- Eloquent Version: **5.3.23**
- PHP Version: **5.6.28**
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL **5.7.16**

Backtrace

```
/path/to/app/shared/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:644 
Illuminate\Container\Container -> make
/path/to/app/shared/vendor/illuminate/database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:130 
call_user_func 
/path/to/app/shared/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php:964 
Illuminate\Database\Connection -> getPdo 
/path/to/app/shared/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php:832 
Illuminate\Database\Connection -> reconnectIfMissingConnection 
/path/to/app/shared/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php:717 
Illuminate\Database\Connection -> run 
/path/to/app/shared/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php:350 
Illuminate\Database\Connection -> select 
/path/to/app/shared/vendor/illuminate/database/Query/Builder.php:1648 
Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder -> runSelect 
/path/to/app/shared/vendor/illuminate/database/Query/Builder.php:1634 
Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder -> get 
/path/to/app/shared/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Builder.php:632 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder -> getModels 
/path/to/app/shared/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Builder.php:327 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder -> get 
/path/to/app/shared/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Builder.php:297 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder -> first 
...
```

I'm suspecting it has something to do with an unregistered error handler:

[github link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/bootstrap/app.php#L39-L42)

But how can I register the custom error handler when not using Laravel?

The solution of @patricus can be implemented as follows:

```
// bootstrap Eloquent ORM
$container = new Container();
$container->singleton(
  'Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler'
, 'My\Custom\DatabaseExceptionHandler'
);

$factory    = new ConnectionFactory( $container );
$connection = $factory->make([
  'driver'    => 'mysql'
, 'host'      => App::config( 'database_host' )
, 'database'  => App::config( 'database_name' )
, 'username'  => App::config( 'database_user' )
, 'password'  => App::config( 'database_password' )
, 'charset'   => App::config( 'database_charset' )
, 'collation' => App::config( 'database_collate' )
, 'prefix'    => ''
]);

$resolver = new ConnectionResolver();
$resolver->addConnection( 'default', $connection );
$resolver->setDefaultConnection( 'default' );

// initialize connection
Model::setConnectionResolver( $resolver );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access the container to register your own exception handler through the capsule.

```
$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager();

$capsule->getContainer()->singleton(
    \Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    \Your\ExceptionHandler\Implementation::class
);
```

If you want a real quick, very dumb, exception handler, you can use this:

```
class DumbExceptionHandler implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler
{
    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        //
    }

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        throw $e;
    }

    public function renderForConsole($output, Exception $e)
    {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

NB: untested. I believe this should work looking at the code.

Comment: Thanks! I added the final solution to my questions.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was permissions issue of system user who executes php command.

Answer (score -6):

Please make sure that your xampp server and the database server is working and running.